# SmartyCache causing intermitten blank page

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-modules

Hi guy all help is appreciated.

I have a site setup in Prestashop (v8.0.4) and the SmartyCache has some issue. Occasionally I will view a product and it will show a blank page. To resolve this issue I have to clear the cache which I guess rebuilds the cache and it functions as normal. There is no pattern in this from what I have noticed.

I have tried to check the error logs no logs show with any reference to this furthermore, when this issue has happened I enabled debug mode even then I just get a blank white page. The HTTP response is the correct 200 response as expected.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, do you still have a blank page when debug mode is on ?
If so, are your permissions correct on all needed directories ?
To check that you can follow this procedure: https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/8/basics/installation/system-requirements/#how-to-verify-your-server-meets-prestashops-requirements